# Did Paul receive The Holy Spirit?

Tags: paul

If you think Paul received The Holy Spirit, please explain the text where you feel this is expressed. Thanks-

Answer (score 4):

Saul encountered Jesus outside of Damascus. He became blind and was taken to a house in the city. After 3 days Jesus sent Ananias to Saul:

> *So Ananias departed and entered the house. And laying his hands on him he said, “Brother Saul, the Lord Jesus who appeared to you on the road by which you came has sent me so that you may regain your sight and be **filled with the Holy Spirit**.” (Acts 9:17 ESV)*

As Saul went on his missionary trips he became known as Paul. There are events which indicate he had the Holy Spirit and times where it is stated he was filled with the Holy Spirit. For example:

> *Then Saul, who also is called Paul, filled with the Holy Spirit, looked intently at him (Acts 13:9 ESV)*

Additional explanation:
The literal translation in both cases would be Spirit Holy: Πνεύματος Ἁγίου. There is no definite article present. "The" is an addition by translators as it is implied based upon the nature of God. If one is filled with "Spirit Holy" from God, then unless there is more than one Holy Spirit, one is filled with "The" Holy Spirit from God.

Comment: I just want to point out that in neither of those verses verses is there a definite article so I believe it should be translated "filled with holy breath" or "filled with holy spirit".

Comment: Wounded Ego, I like your comment. The definite article is important to me. Except Revelation has "the" before "Holy Spirit" -is the definite article added in the ESV? Also, if you are so inclined, I would like to see you expand on your comment by posting the Koine Greek and the translation, and from where you are deriving that -which manuscripts? Thank you